All orders of the last day of the month for each employee
Using the Northwind database on Microsoft SQL Server, I'm trying to
find the last day of each month on which each employee has placed an order,
as well as all the orders on that day by that employee.
for example: 1996-07-17 was the last day of month when employee 1 has placed an order. I want all the orders by employee 1 from this day.
select EmployeeID, max(convert(date, orderdate)) as LastDay
from northwind.dbo.Orders
group by YEAR(OrderDate),MONTH(OrderDate),EmployeeID
order by EmployeeID,LastDay;

This query returns the last days of months for each employee, but I couldn't get the orders.

Seems like a Get top 1 row of each group but using (DENSE_)RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.

this is a variation of Get TOP 1 of group where group is year/month combo. LOL, @ThomA beat me to it

Does this answer your question? Get top 1 row of each group

Maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/JdZ2gw60

Solution using a CTE. Since 2 was the max number of orders any employee placed on the last day of the month we can get a compact result set using STRING_AGG.
WITH CTE as 
(  
SELECT EmployeeID, max(convert(date, orderdate)) as LastDay
FROM Orders
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate),MONTH(OrderDate),EmployeeID
)
SELECT c.EmployeeID, 
       c.LastDay as LastDayOFMonth,
       Count(*) as [Order Count], 
       STRING_AGG(o.orderID,',') as [Orders] 
FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN CTE c on c.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
                AND c.LastDay=convert(date, o.orderdate)
GROUP BY c.EmployeeID, c.LastDay
ORDER BY c.EmployeeID, c.LastDay

fiddle



EmployeeID
LastDayOFMonth
Order Count
Orders




1
1998-04-21
2
11038,11039



1 example of 192 rows returned

thanks for your helpful solution, how do I show the orders of column orders in separate rows below each other?

Try this for all order details https://dbfiddle.uk/nap5xsAf  Notice for emp #1 on 1998-04-21 you have 2 rows.

@T N  thanks. good catch. Query corrected.

This solution uses DENSE_RANK and is more efficient
WITH CTE as 
(  
SELECT o.*,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate),MONTH(OrderDate),EmployeeID ORDER BY orderdate DESC) AS rn
FROM Orders o
) 
SELECT c.EmployeeID, 
       c.orderdate as LastDayOFMonth,
       c.orderID
FROM cte c
WHERE c.rn=1  
ORDER BY c.EmployeeID, c.orderdate

fiddle
fiddle with cost comparison



EmployeeID
LastDayOfMonth
OrderID




1
1996-07-17
10258


1
1996-08-29
10293


1
1996-09-27
10316


1
1996-10-29
10340


1
1996-11-26
10364


1
1996-12-27
10396


1
1997-01-06
10405


1
1997-02-28
10461


1
1997-03-26
10486


1
1997-04-16
10508


1
1997-05-23
10546


1
1997-06-25
10579


1
1997-07-31
10616


1
1997-08-13
10630


1
1997-09-24
10680


1
1997-10-27
10718


1
1997-11-19
10746


1
1997-12-26
10800


1
1998-01-29
10859


1
1998-02-27
10916


1
1998-03-30
10984


1
1998-04-21
11038


1
1998-04-21
11039



